# Automate Windows Hello PIN setup

Tags: powershell, .net-framework, c#, windows-hello

I am investigating the feasibility of deploying Windows Hello in a busy work environment. The area contains 40+ shared PCs, with 200+ roaming users. Also, a subset of the users are replaced regularly (3 months).

I would like to allow users to login with a PIN as opposed to a password, but manually setting each user up on each PC every three months would not be feasible.

Is there a way to set each users PIN on each of the PCs automatically using Powershell, by creating a small .Net application or by using a third party service? I have been unable to find any documentation or APIs online.

Comment: If I remember correctly PIN are replacement / alternative method of login to the standard username/password - so you will not have the ability to pre-set PIN on behalf of someone else to my knowledge. The most you can do is to enable Windows Hello / PIN using Group Policy - and then advise your users to set up PIN as they see fit (as they may not want to use PIN, and they may opt for other Windows Hello feature eg Face, Fingerprint, Security Key, Picture Password).

Comment: @Darius Yes, that is correct. However the problem I have is the users are not technically savvy (or patient) and if it is not set up for them they will not do it themselves. Its a "unique" dynamic. We are then back to our current situation of constant support requests to reset passwords.

Comment: How about string up a way so users can self service to reset their password? Yes the usual security question is not very safe or sending reset link to their registered alternative email or SMS code .. but it will reduce the service call for password reset if that is your end goal.

Comment: @Darius Thanks for the suggestion, we have a system like that in place already but a certain percentage of our user base wouldn't use it, this is not an office environment. The PIN will also speed up logins which is its other main benefit.